# Json encoding with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, json, encode

I am trying to data to json, I can hardcode the output but the code needs to be generated dynamically using MySQL data and some code to calculate the results.
The json output will be in this format:

```
    {
      "inits": {
"version": "18.05.04_EP1",
"source": "Live",
"lowid": "265067",
"highid": "265068",
"ql": "300",
"name": "Ofab Shark Mk 1",
"inits": [
  {
    "-init": "430",
    "-percent": "100",
    "-slider": "DEF>===========][<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "530",
    "-percent": "90",
    "-slider": "DEF>==========][=<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "630",
    "-percent": "81",
    "-slider": "DEF>=========][==<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "730",
    "-percent": "72",
    "-slider": "DEF>========][===<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "830",
    "-percent": "63",
    "-slider": "DEF>=======][====<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "930",
    "-percent": "54",
    "-slider": "DEF>======][=====<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "1030",
    "-percent": "45",
    "-slider": "DEF>=====][======<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "1130",
    "-percent": "36",
    "-slider": "DEF>====][=======<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "1290",
    "-percent": "27",
    "-slider": "DEF>===][========<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "1590",
    "-percent": "18",
    "-slider": "DEF>==][=========<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "1890",
    "-percent": "9",
    "-slider": "DEF>=][==========<AGG"
  },
  {
    "-init": "2190",
    "-percent": "0",
    "-slider": "DEF>][===========<AGG"
  }
]
```

}
}

the "inits": [init, percent, slider] needs to be inside a loop to generate the results.
I can do this statically by using:

```
    array (
   'inits' => 
 array (
'version' => '18.05.04_EP1',
'source' => 'Live',
'lowid' => '265067',
'highid' => '265068',
'ql' => '300',
'name' => 'Ofab Shark Mk 1',
'inits' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '430',
    '-percent' => '100',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>===========][<AGG',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '530',
    '-percent' => '90',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>==========][=<AGG',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '630',
    '-percent' => '81',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>=========][==<AGG',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '730',
    '-percent' => '72',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>========][===<AGG',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '830',
    '-percent' => '63',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>=======][====<AGG',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '930',
    '-percent' => '54',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>======][=====<AGG',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '1030',
    '-percent' => '45',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>=====][======<AGG',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '1130',
    '-percent' => '36',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>====][=======<AGG',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '1290',
    '-percent' => '27',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>===][========<AGG',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '1590',
    '-percent' => '18',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>==][=========<AGG',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '1890',
    '-percent' => '9',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>=][==========<AGG',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    '-init' => '2190',
    '-percent' => '0',
    '-slider' => 'DEF>][===========<AGG',
  ),
),
```

),
)

However, I have no idea how to call any methods to fill in the array data for each array (init,percent,slider). I am new to PHP, and am having hard time finding the correct usage of PHP, I am a c# developer. If anyone can help I would appreciate it!

Comment: Append to arrays with `$data["inits"]["inits"][] = array(430, 100, "DEF");` or so.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Did you mean PHP **5**.3? The last 4.3 release was in 2005, and PHP 4 as a whole has been officially discontinued since the end of 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for`. I don't know what exactly you want fo fill, but the code will be aso folowing:

```
//Let $ar be the array you have posted
for($i=0;$i<count($ar["inits"]["inits"]); $i++) {
   $ar["inits"]["inits"][$i]["-slider"]="something";
}
```